# How to show a validation message to blade Laravel json response()

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I have confused in her, my plan is I wanna get my error validation message from my `response()->json()` in controller and show it in my `blade.php` but I can't made them call into my blade, but when I check my result link in my console, my message validation is showing it, who's anyone know my problem, I put my code in bellow :

my controller :

```
public function testApi(Request $api)
{
   $validator = Validator:make($api->all(), [
      'name_product' => 'required'
   ]);

   if () {
      return response()->json([
         'error' => $validator->messages()
      ], 401);
   } else {
     // my condition if validator is not fail
   }
}
```

my blade :

```
@if ($errors->any())
   <h4>{{ $error->first() }}</h4>
@endif
@csrf
<div>
    <label>Name Product</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_product" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" id="productButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Add">
</div>
```

my js :

```
document.querySelector('#productButton').addEventListener('click', addProduct);

let urlProduct = '/product/add';
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

function addProduct() {
   let nameProduct = document.querySelector('input[name="name_product"]').value;

   fetch(urlProduct, {
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
           "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
      },
      method: 'post',
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: JSON.stringfy({
          name_product = nameProduct
      })
   }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
   }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   })
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Not using fetch() then() correctly. `data` is actually the response object and data.json() is a promise for the actual server data

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Try `fetch(url, {/* options*/}).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))`

Comment: it's work, after that I just call my error into my blade?

Comment: I have error again when validation is true my error change to this `register:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` what should I do?

Comment: means returning html not json. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. Look at what is actually returned in the response body there

Comment: well I need my error value in my console and it's work and I already show that message, but when my validation is not false (I mean the form is already input), and the error is show like in above

Comment: Go into browser dev tools (F12) and on network dig deep into the actual request and read what the html output tells you in response body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making `ajax` call, and the page is not refreshed, when you submit the `post` request so this

```php
@if ($errors->any())
   <h4>{{ $error->first() }}</h4>
@endif
```

will not be re-rendered again. So all the `blade error` will not work for you if you send `ajax` request.

You can just do this:

```php
<h4 id="error"></h4>
```

```js
.then((data) => {
         const h4 = document.getElementById("error");
         h4.innerHTML = data.error;
   })
```